# How can I set the secret token for gitlab plugin with Jenkins job dsl?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-job-dsl

The documentation from the plugin site seems to be wrong: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin

Example from job dsl documentation: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.TriggerContext.gitlabPush

In `GitLabPushTrigger` you can set `secretToken` but how can I set it via job dsl?

My current Job:

```
job('seed-job-v2') {

    description('Job that makes sure a service has a build pipeline available')

    triggers {
        gitlabPush {}
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL):

```
job('example') {
  triggers {
    gitlab {
      secretToken('foo')
    }
  }
}
```

The dynamic DSL supports almost all config options.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative would be this

```
job('Test') {
    triggers {
        gitlabPush {
        }
    }
    configure {
        it / triggers / 'com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.GitLabPushTrigger' << secretToken('SECRET')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is direct support for this in `pipelineTriggers` which you can only view in the live API viewer in you jenkins server.

Refer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111017/1606098