# Correct syntax for pipelineTriggers

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a seed job that is based off of DSL. This is what is looks like

```
pipelineJob("job name") {
        description('Some explanation')
        triggers {
                cron('@midnight')
                upstream('someJob', 'SUCCESS')
        }
        parameters {
        ...
```

When I run the job, it ends up being unstable with the error message

```
Warning: (Builds.groovy, line 53) triggers is deprecated
```

So now Ive re written the code as follows

```
pipelineJob("job name") {
        description('Some explanation')
        properties {
            pipelineTriggers {
                triggers {
                        cron('@midnight')
                        upstream('someJob', 'SUCCESS')
                }
            }
         parameters {
         ...
```

And now I get the error

```
ERROR: (unknown source) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.structs.DescribableListContext.cron() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [@midnight]
Possible solutions: grep(), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), any()
```

Now ive re-written it as

```
pipelineJob("job name") {
        description('Some explanation')
        properties {
            pipelineTriggers {
                triggers {
                        cron{
                            spec('@midnight')
                        }
                        upstream('someJob', 'SUCCESS')
                }
            }
         parameters {
         ...
```

But now this ends up with the error

```
ERROR: (Builds.groovy, line 72) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.structs.DescribableListContext.upstream() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [someJob, SUCCESS]
```

What else have I missed here ?

Answer (score 5):

Using the URL `<JENKINS_URL>/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#path/pipelineJob-properties-pipelineTriggers-triggers`

I got the correct format

```
        properties {
            pipelineTriggers {
                triggers {
                        cron {
                            spec('@midnight')
                            }
                        upstream{
                            upstreamProjects('someJob')
                            threshold('SUCCESS')
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```